# Flutter FirebaseMessaging - StreamSubscription not handled properly

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a the following basic example, which does not seem to work properly:

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0
```

**FcmService.dart**

```
StreamSubscription fcmListener;

void init() {
   fcmListener = FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
     // do stuff
   });
}

void dispose() {
   print('SUBSCRIPTION canceled');
   fcmListener.cancel()
}
```

**App.dart**

```
void init() {
   fcmService.init();
   // other inits()
}

void dispose() {
   print('EVERYTHING disposed');
   fcmService.dispose();
   // other disposes()
}
```

## Problem

After I log in into my app the `init()` method of App.dart is called, and everything is set up properly. The FCM service works all fine. When I log-out of the app the `dispose()` method of App.dart is called and the app redirects to Login.dart. The proper logs are `EVERYTHING disposed` and `SUBSCRIPTION canceled`.

However,if I log in again (without hot reloading the app) I get the following error message, regarding `fcmListener = FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen()`

`Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events while doing an addStream`. Although, the FCMService still works as expected.

This only happens in the new firebase_messaging, which they rewrote a while ago. I used this same code with a previous version of firebase_messaging, and this exception did not occur.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `.asBroadcastStream()` after `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage`:

```dart
void init() {
  fcmListener = FirebaseMessaging
    .onMessage
    .asBroadcastStream()
    .listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // do stuff
    });
}
```

The same method should be called with `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp`. I have found this solution in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6009#issuecomment-832643710).

Answer (score 0):

you can use subscribe and topics feature in firebase cloud messaging. this is another easy way.

```
Login
FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic("guest");
FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("loggedIn");

Logout
FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("guest");
FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic("loggedIn");

FCM Api = 
{
 "to" : "/topics/loggedin",
 "notification" : {
     "title" : "your title notification",
     "body" : "your body notification"
 }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).